# webpack config when release the project to server

Tags: webpack

recently,i have written a project with the help of webpack(+webpack-dev-server),and now i want to push it to the server of the company,however,i'm confused that when i only push the built js and html to the server.  it still  request for the localhost:3001(which is my build output path).my config is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
entry: getEntries(),

output:{
    path:BUILD_DIR,
    filename:"[name].bundle.js",
    // publicPath:"/monitor/",
    publicPath:"http://localhost:3001/build/"
},
```

how can i change to the company's server?

Answer (score 0):

publicPath : You can point to the relative path like '/build' ; Webapck will automatically load the bundle from that path;
I have something like the below in production.
Depending on the environment, I create a json file which the webpack uses to load the assets and the build file.
output: {
    path: buildPath,
    filename: 'app-201.js',
    chunkFilename: 'app-2012.js',
    publicPath: '/sample/build/'
  }

Comment: if i should push the built js file to the company server,what the public path should be ? and i wanna know if it's necessary?